# Xamarin Android Archive Library (aar) binding. SharedPreferences issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to create a xamarin binding project for aar library. But if I add interface or class which extends `SharedPreferences`, it is not compiled. How to fix this?
See screenshot with logs below
[image]

I also created a project to demonstrate the issue.
https://github.com/3akat/SharedPrefsXamarinBindingIssueDemo

Comment: Your binding arr library is `app-debug.aar`?I test it in my VS, I got the same error.But i changed another arr(such as  textanalyzer.aar), that is normal, so this issue is related to this .arr file, First of all, make sure your arr file contains the following:

Compiled Java code
Resource IDs
Resources
Meta-data (for example, Activity declarations, permissions) ,There is a basic troubleshot article ,you could refer to it.https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/

Comment: Yup, I'm binding `app-debug.aar`. This `aar` is generated from android project in the same repository. In andorid project I have nothing except `TestInterface` which extends `SharedPreferences` interface.

Comment: Based on my research, this issue is related to your arr file. Can you  check the code of .arr file.